# EJS stream with fetches

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, asynchronous, ejs

I am curious, is it possible to livestream data from an api without reloading the page.
I'm interested in redeclaring all variables that the view/page was rendered with from start of - Make a async fetch in the background, which then will redeclare the variables and rerender them in some manner.

I'm not quite sure to which approach i should have - it's basicly an idea where i have school activities fetched from an api and rendered through ejs. But i would like a realtime effect, where as i don't need to reload the page to make another fetch to see the variables being rerendered with the fresh data??

I know i could make an AJAX call on the clientside, which means i would have to rewrite my ejs file
But that's not what i'm looking for...

**Is it possible to livestream data with ejs in any way?**

````
        <svg class="Bg" viewBox="0 0 201.305 94">
          <path fill="rgba(50,50,69,1)" class="pathBg" d="M 0 0 L 201.3046875 0 L 201.3046875 94 L 0 94 L 0 0 Z">
          </path>
        </svg>
        <svg class="before" viewBox="0 0 16 94">
          <% switch (elem.color) {
            case "green": %>
            <path fill="#78952b" class="pathbefore" d="M 0 0 L 16 0 L 16 94 L 0 94 L 0 0 Z">
                    <% break;
            case "red": %>
            <path fill="#A83331" class="pathbefore" d="M 0 0 L 16 0 L 16 94 L 0 94 L 0 0 Z">
                    <% break;
            case "purple": %>
            <path fill="#7D2772" class="pathbefore" d="M 0 0 L 16 0 L 16 94 L 0 94 L 0 0 Z">
                    <% break;
            case "blue": %>
            <path fill="#3674B5" class="pathbefore" d="M 0 0 L 16 0 L 16 94 L 0 94 L 0 0 Z">
                    <% break;
            default: case "grey": %>
            <path fill="#808080" class="pathbefore" d="M 0 0 L 16 0 L 16 94 L 0 94 L 0 0 Z">
                    <% break;
            } %>


          </path>
        </svg>
        <div class="holdNavn">
          <span><%= elem.class %></span>
        </div>
        <svg class="tidBg" viewBox="0 0 167 19">
          <path fill="rgba(36,36,57,1)" class="pathtidBg"
            d="M 9.5 0 L 157.5 0 C 162.7467041015625 0 167 4.253294467926025 167 9.5 C 167 14.74670600891113 162.7467041015625 19 157.5 19 L 9.5 19 C 4.253294467926025 19 0 14.74670600891113 0 9.5 C 0 4.253294467926025 4.253294467926025 0 9.5 0 Z">
          </path>
        </svg>
        <div class="hold">
          <span>Hold</span>
        </div>
        <div class="emneNavn">
          <span><%=  elem.friendly_name %></span>
        </div>
        <div class="emne">
          <span>Emne</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tidStart">
          <span><%= elem.time %></span>
        </div>
        <div class="lokaleNummer">
          <span><%= elem.classroom %></span>
        </div>
        <div class="tid">
          <span>Tid</span>
        </div>
        <div class="lokale">
          <span>Lokale</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <% }) %>
    </div>```
````

Comment: If the data on the server side is constantly changing then you could use [`WebSockets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications). If the changing data is based on user interaction then using a HTTP request would also work.

Comment: This is meant to be a non interactive dashboard, but would you suggest me sockets io or something in that caliber?

Comment: Maybe thats a solution. But *live streaming* something is broad. Streaming video makes sense, but I'm not sure if the terminology is suitable. Do you want the client to receive updates whenever the data is changed, like real-time-communication. And how often is the data changed?

Comment: Yeah okay - well I would like to have a real-time application - where I can recieve new data whenever the fetched data is changed. So if there's new activities, then I can make them appear in real-time - the data from the API is changed once every four hours or so.

Comment: Then websockets are the way to go. Personally I've had good experiences with [socket.io](https://socket.io/), but any library with sockets would do. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I will research it further, thanks for giving me a wink! ;)